# Deploy rails site from local to justhost server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-deployment

I am new to rails and this question might be very basic. I learnt ruby on rails to create a small site which i have tested on herokuapp as well.

Now, I want to deploy it in the actual site which is hosted on justhost.

How should the application be deployed? Is there any way we could move the herokuapp directly to the server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok! I was just wondering about the database configuration, server settings etc in addition to the ftp files upload. The following link looks good for the entire process [link](http://www.buildingwebapps.com/podcasts/79347-deploying-to-a-public-web-server) I was thinking why we need to do all these again because we do the same in herokuapp, and if there is any auto-migration tool to move from herokuapp to the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking their help section? This tutorial from their website should show you everything you need: https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/upload-site

Comment: Thanks for answering. I downloaded an ftp program already. However I would like to know the steps for uploading a ruby on rails app and if there is a shortcut to move from heroku app to the new server.

Comment: It seems that there is no shortcut. Transferring the website through FTP, however, shouldn't be that hard. For a step by step instruction follow the link I sent you, choose the FTP program you downloaded and just follow the instructions.